# How to list all root folder and shares on the Google Drive API v3 while paging and using order by?

Tags: java, android, google-api, google-drive-api, google-drive-android-api

I've seen a few questions about this but none cover my scenario.

Basically what I want is to use tokens to do paging and also list all folders and files in the root folder including shared files and folders.

This appears to be working, but once I add `orderBy` it doesn't work well. It works ok with sorting if I remove `or sharedWithMe = true` but once I add it it like the shared items aren't sorted.

What am I doing wrong?

This is my code (Kotlin and on Android):

```
val response =
 gDriveClient.files()
 .list()
 .setSpaces("drive")
 .setCorpora("user")
 .setFields("files(id, name, size, modifiedTime, mimeType, parents, quotaBytesUsed),nextPageToken")
 .setQ("('root' in parents or sharedWithMe = true) and trashed = false")
 .setOrderBy("folder,name")
 .setPageSize(params.loadSize)
 .setPageToken(token)
```

Comment: So you want to basically retrieve all your folders including those in shared Drives and order then by name right? What behaviour do you get when listing them with ```sharedWithMe = true``` (i.e you get the folders unordered, the shared folders at the end, etc)?

Comment: Not just folders, I want to list files as well on the root folder and shared stuff. I have not found a pattern yet, the files and folders just feel mixed when I use `sharedWithMe = true` and it isn't just the shared ones that are mixed, my own files are mixed in between them, however if I take `folder` out of the `orderBy` then the files aren't mixed, I get shared first and mine second, but the order by `name` is still wrong. If I take `root in parents` then it  seems to be sorted. So it the mixing of both I think but in batches, I'll get some from shared and some mine then shared and so on.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Unfortunately, the behaviour you are experiencing seems to be a bug as your query and request is formatted correctly and necessary to obtain exactly what you were looking for. I have reported this behaviour here : https://issuetracker.google.com/issues/174476354 . Please consider starring the report to indicate that this is also affecting you.

#### Workaround

A possible workaround to this would be to order and filter your response after the request has been executed which unfortunately will not let you perform the request with pagination for your specific purpose (as for ordering everything you would need all the files).

#### References

- [Drive.Files.list()](https://developers.google.com/drive/api/v3/reference/files/list)
- [Query parameter sharedWithMe](https://developers.google.com/drive/api/v3/reference/query-ref#fields)

Comment: Thank you, I think that could solve it but when I look I don't see `setSupportsAllDrives` as a method. What version of their api do you have? Android Studio shows I have `google-api-services-drive-v3-rev136-1.25.0`.

Comment: Found `v3-rev197-1.25.0` and that seems to have it. However I still don't see shared one with the `root in parents` and if I take that out I see a ton of files and folders. I'm guessing it is listing all everywhere?

Comment: Just to be clear. If I use the code as you posted, I see a ton of files, my guess is that it is every file everywhere on every drive. If I use `root in parents` then I see only those that have `root` as parent which means I don't see any shared stuff. Some shared items do seem to have a parent, but a lot of them don't.

Comment: Hi ! Yes, so after taking a further look I realised that in order to satisfy your conditions your approach was better. However, I have realised that the fact that ```sharedWithMe``` messed up the order was not an expected behaviour and therefore I have reported this to Google. Check the report [here](https://issuetracker.google.com/issues/174476354) and consider starring it to indicate that this behaviour is also affecting you. Would you consider a workaround ordering the files after the request has been done rather than within the request?

Comment: Thanks for filing that. Because of this issue I am planning on sorting myself after making the request (like I do with Dropbox) but that means I won't be able to use paging.

Comment: You could divide your returned and oredered list of files into different objects of size page size and then apply pagination. How about that workaround?

Comment: The purpose of the pagination is in case the network calls are slow or too large, not so much for stuff already in memory on the phone. Once the query has been made to the network to get the data then returning all the data isn't a huge deal and sorting is simple. If you edit your answer to include your report and specify that it is a bug then I can make you as the correct answer.